# How to add a column to an already existing table in apache pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I already have a table created using Pig. Now I want to add a random number with every row(record) to give me a new table with this added column.

Is this possible and how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use the [RANDOM](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#random) UDF for this purpose.
E.g:

```
A = ...
B = foreach A generate (int)(RANDOM()*100.0) as rnd, [other fields...]
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this.